# How to set wallpaper for lock screen in iPhone or iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

I have gone through many of similar post that I have asked here. I have understood that there is no public API for doing this in iOS devices and if we use the private API for this purpose, apple will not accept it too. But I have found an application in itunes which does the same feature.

Here is the link :
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sticky-notes-hd-with-bump/id364874025?mt=8

If apple do not support this, how this application is in Appstore. Then they may have did this in some other way. So I hope this feature can be implemented somehow.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thats impossible to do.

Have you bought the app you referenced to? Did you see it?

Comment: I have downloaded the lite version of the app, in which there is an option to set it as wallpaper for lockscreen.

Answer (score 0):

The app that you reference generates a picture that you -- by hand -- need to set as lockscreen/wallpaper.

One thing that goes in that direction is the [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html); it allows you to set what's being shown in the "now playing" info on the lock screen, but that's about how far you will get.